# Adding custom $.Validator.AddMethod for HTML.DropDownList

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can i add a custom $.validator.addMethod in jQuery for HTML.DropDownList

Need validation to check a valid selection is made.  Is there any sample someone can direct it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by a valid selection? I'm assuming you're talking about `<select>` elements, and if each of the "valid" `<option>`s has a `value="something"` attribute then I think jquery-validator handles it already, if you add `class="required"` to the `<select>`